# Sed multiple replacement rules at once

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to fix broken characters in a file by converting `windows-1252` to `windows-1251` 
I want to do mapping that looks like:
`sed 's/[ÉÖÓÊÅÍÃØÙÇÕÚÔÛÂÀÏÐÎËÄÆÝß×ÑÌÈÒÜÁÞ¸éöóêåíãøùçõúôûâàïðîëäæýÿ÷ñìèòüáþ]/[ЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю]/g' input.py > input.py`

I can replace characters one by one like:

```
sed 's/î/о/g'  input.py > output1.py
sed 's/è/и/g'  output1.py > input.py
```

But what is the syntax for character mapping to fix all characters in one run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `tr` is for. Assuming those really are the characters you want to change and this isn't an encoding issue, what you need is:

```
tr '¨ÉÖÓÊÅÍÃØÙÇÕÚÔÛÂÀÏÐÎËÄÆÝß×ÑÌÈÒÜÁÞ¸éöóêåíãøùçõúôûâàïðîëäæýÿ÷ñìèòüáþ' \
   'ЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю' < input.py > output.py
```

However, I suspect what you want to do is to change the encoding of the file, not the characters. I can't test this without an example file, but perhaps this:

```
 iconv -f windows-1252 -t windows-1251 input.py > output.py
```

Comment: I've fixed the replacement rule a bit and now your `tr` method works exactly as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @Stepan great, thanks for the edit. Are you sure it works though? On my tests, your new replacement gave some very strange results, including sanskrit characters. This could be because I was testing on a UTF-8 file, however.

Comment: Also, to answer the OP's question, `y` is the `sed` to command to transliterate characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh, duh! I should have thought of that! Might be worth posting as an answer.